# Example of invalid URI as per RFC 3986

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rfc3986

For my unit test I'd like to find an example of invalid URI that will fail to match `UriComponentsBuilder#URI_PATTERN` regex from Spring MVC 3.1.1:

```
private static final String SCHEME_PATTERN = "([^:/?#]+):";

private static final String HTTP_PATTERN = "(http|https):";

private static final String USERINFO_PATTERN = "([^@/]*)";

private static final String HOST_PATTERN = "([^/?#:]*)";

private static final String PORT_PATTERN = "(\\d*)";

private static final String PATH_PATTERN = "([^?#]*)";

private static final String QUERY_PATTERN = "([^#]*)";

private static final String LAST_PATTERN = "(.*)";

// Regex patterns that matches URIs. See RFC 3986, appendix B
private static final Pattern URI_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "^(" + SCHEME_PATTERN + ")?" + "(//(" + USERINFO_PATTERN + "@)?" + HOST_PATTERN + "(:" + PORT_PATTERN +
                ")?" + ")?" + PATH_PATTERN + "(\\?" + QUERY_PATTERN + ")?" + "(#" + LAST_PATTERN + ")?");
```

I'm struggling to find a single string that will cause `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString()` to fail with `IllegalArgumentException`. Anything I try passes regex check as valid URI.

Answer (score 3):

I think anything will match that regex.  The problem is that the regex doesn't implement the RFC strictly.  Rather, it is designed to be permissive; i.e. to accept any old rubbish and make a best-effort attempt to parse it as a URL.

(However, I note that it won't do a decent job of parsing non-HTTP URIs.  Look at the  `SCHEME_PATTERN` ... and weep.)

If you want to do strict parsing or validation of URIs, you would be better off using `java.net.URI`.  Regexes are not the right tool for this task.

Comment: their HTTP URL pattern is more strict: `private static final Pattern HTTP_URL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
   "^" + HTTP_PATTERN + "(//(" + USERINFO_PATTERN + "@)?" + HOST_PATTERN + "(:" + PORT_PATTERN + ")?" + ")?" +
     PATH_PATTERN + "(\\?" + LAST_PATTERN + ")?");`

Comment: it doesn't accept `fragment` part which is strange, do you think it is a bug?

Comment: *"Do you think it is a bug?"* - You'd need to argue that with the Spring MVC developers.  My take is that using regexes for URL/URI parsing is a whole nest of bugs.  Just don't do it.